# How to change Ext js store data dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a combobox which looks like below

```
{
  xtype:'combo',
  fieldLabel:'Test',
  store:['a','b']
}
```

Without creating Ext store object I am assigning the array to store and it is displaying the values fine.

At some action i want to update the store with ['d','e']

I have tried by assigning the new values to store like below

```
comboObje.store=['d','e'];
```

but it is not updating the values.

how to replace the orginal values with new values in the store.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a new store using `bindStore` or just load new data to the existing store using `loadData`:

```
combo.store.loadData(['d', 'e'].map(function(item){ return [item]; }));
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tb1

Answer (score 3):

In version 5.* and higher you can use:

```
comboObje.setStore(['d','e']);
```

This doesn't work in previous versions.

Paste the following code into a [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home) as a 'proof-of-concept':

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var panel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'test',
            items: [{
                xtype:'combo',
                fieldLabel:'Test',
                store:['a','b']
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        panel.down('combo').setStore(['d','e']);
    }
});
```

Comment: It is absolutely working. No doubt. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Ok let me make a fiddle

Comment: Nope your example is not working in http://jsfiddle.net/tsuryap/6zfcbnzz/11/ .. I am using Ext js 4.2 I was lol when i executed your example in in fiddle

Comment: Your proof of concept is failed in ext js 4.2

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Didn't realize that `setStore` doesn't exist in 4.2.*. In 5.* and higher it works perfectly though. Sorry to point you in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
comboObje.getStore().loadData([{'field1': 'd'}, {'field1': 'e'}]);
```

When you assign an array to 'store' config, ExtJS automatically generates field names.